# EBADENGINE warning when setting up a NestJS project using NVM

Tags: nestjs

New node dev here. Installed NVM and use latest Node LTS:

```
node --version: v16.13.0
npm --version: 8.1.2
```

When I follow instructions on Nest documentation:

```
npm i -g @nestjs/cli
```

I get the following warnings:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/core@12.2.10',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.1.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/schematics@12.2.10',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.1.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/schematics-cli@12.2.10',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.1.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

So, is there an issue using NestJS with NVM?

Comment: NPM v8.1.2 is indeed incompatible with the requirement of `^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I upgraded NPM afterwards thinking an upgrade would solve the above EBADENGINE issues, so I did: nvm install-latest-npm. Prior to this I had NPM 8.1.0 with the same issues.

Comment: How would _upgrading_ NPM fix that, given it's telling you the version you're using is already too new? 8.1.2 is no more compatible with that specification than 8.1.0 was.

Comment: just ignore them. Or switch to Yarn xD

Comment: I'll downgrade NPM and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: npm install -g npm@7.5.6 works! - this changed the NPM version on my current node. Regarding Yarn, it may be faster and better but I'm new to Node (coming from Java) and I want minimal config overhead - also NPM comes with Node so it's more standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each version of Node came with a bundled version of NPM, so when installing/use a specific Node version using NVM it also sets the NPM version for that specific Node version that originally was bundled with it.

Here's a JSON of NodeJS distributions that indicates each Node version and the NPM bundled with it: https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json

The above warnings tell us what the problem is:

```
required: {
    node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0',
    npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6',
},
```

Means that I can use a newer Node version than v14 (example: LTS/gallium) but it's bundled NPM version (8.1.0) doesn't meet the above requirement, allowing a latest minor & patch version of 7.5.6.

While using Node v16 in NVM I could change it's NPM version to latest v7.x.x by running:

```
npm install -g npm@7.24.2
```

After this there were no more warning scaffolding a Nest project (at least for now).